# Malwarebytes Block Outbound Connections (Guest-to-Host On VBox)

Tags: windows, linux

While I am using other OS (Mostly Linux) in VBox and start Downloding from torrents, 
the host (Windows 10) that I have Installed Malwarebytes block Outbound Connections?

Can it be dangerous when the trial ends
[[image: Photo 1[1]]

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are downloading from a suspicious ip. Maybe that ip is in a blacklist... and that kind of things usually is because of a reason.

Torrent downloads are usually a way to propagate malware... so could be dangerous. Keep your eyes open and check carefully what you download before opening it, that's all.